# Want to design a printer friendly website; anything I should keep in mind?

Tags: html, css

I want to design a website with a bunch of content, and I want that content to be printer friendly. So basically just the content. No navigation, no ads, no nothing. I'm planning on creating two stylesheets, one for printer and one for screen.

**Q1:** Is this the best way?

**Q2:** Is there anything I should keep in mind while designing this site? Should I use *width:960px;* or would a *width:95%;* approach be better?

**Q3:** What font size is the best on print?

**Q4:** Is a serif or san-serif font better for print?

Loads of questions, please help :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:** I would use two CSS files as you propose. That way the HTML is reused and you don't have to manage extra resources other than the print CSS style.

**Q2:** I would use relative units like percentage or EMs rather than pixels. (How would you expect a pixel to relate to the print?) Remember that the page might not be printed on an A4 page, could be A3, A5 - anything. For widths I usually prefer EMs as usually the best length for a line of text is between 60 to 80 characters (60em to 80ems). Longer and the eye strains to follow the text. Shorter and you end up with not enough space for longer words and you get undesired word-wrapping. Relative units will make the page scale to whatever format it's printed to. (Which is why I also recommend relative units for screen as well.)

**Q3:** Assuming an A4 page, I'd go for nothing less than 10pt, - maybe 12pt. Depending on your content. The best way is to print out a test and judge for yourself how well it reads.

**Q4:** It is generally said that sans-serif fonts works best on screen - because the serifs are hard to represent well on the low resolution of (current) monitors. Whereas serif fonts are generally considered to be better for print.
This is an interesting area though and there are some disputes - which you can quickly find if you dig up some reading on the matter. What I suggested is what the general accepted convention is.

Comment: Very good and complete answer. Keep it up! +1